# Intellij not picking up correct execution policy for powershell

Tags: powershell, intellij-idea, terminal, executionpolicy

Ive changed my Powershell execution policy from `Restricted` to `RemoteSigned`. If I open up a new Powershell terminal and run `Get-ExecutionPolicy` I get back `RemoteSigned`.

I've also setup Powershell to run in Intellij instead of the default command prompt. However when I run `Get-ExecutionPolicy` in Intellij's terminals (note: I have restarted Intellij after changing the policy) I still get back `Restricted`.

Why is that and how do I get Intellij to pick up my actual execution policy?

Comment: Did you change user or computer policy?

Comment: @PetSerAl How can I tell? I opened a powershell window in admin mode and said `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.

Comment: Do same thing for PowerShell x86.

Comment: @PetSerAl Looks like that worked! If you make that an answer I'll accept. Now do you know how to get Intellij to use 64bit Powershell?

Comment: Figured it out - was running the 32 bit version of Intellij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple scopes of PowerShell execution policy (`MachinePolicy`, `UserPolicy`, `Process`, `CurrentUser`, `LocalMachine`). You can read about them in build-in PowerShell help: [`Get-Help about_Execution_Policies`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847748.aspx). But what is not mentioned in that help is, that `LocalMachine` scope is separate for x86 and x64. So, if you changing execution policy in `LocalMachine` scope, which used by default if you does not specify `-Scope` parameter for `Set-ExecutionPolicy` cmdlet, than you have to do it twice: once for x86 and once for x64.